# How to efficiently test a JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Assume the following class & its repository:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    //getters , setters, Contructors
    
}
```

And the Repository is :

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {}
```

What I did to test is : Configure the `application.properties` for H2 database and create the following class :

```
import com.ndongoel.myDHL.repositories.AdresseRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class LoadDB {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDB.class);

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(AdresseRepository adresseRepository) {
        return args -> {
            Student stu = new Student(null,"Mike","Smith");
            log.info("Preloading " + studentRepository.save(stu));
    }
}
```

And just Check the console and The H2 database!

Comment: You can use test containers and do the integration test.

Answer (score -1):

Test with `testcontainers` config looks as follows:

```
mport org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {InternalErrorTest.Initializer.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class InternalErrorTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setTest() {
        DockerProxy.setTesting(true);
        postgreSQLContainer.start();
    }

    @ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer =
            new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:11.1")
                    .withDatabaseName("myName")
                    .withUsername("myUsername")
                    .withPassword("myPassword");

    static class Initializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
              props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", testUrl);
        }
    }


    //your tests...

}
```